# Gulp-sass not compiling Bourbon.io @include Transition

Tags: sass, gulp, bourbon

I upgraded my version of gulp-sass today and gulp itself and I'm having issues with Bourbon.io

In Sass the style reads:

```
.dropdown-is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    @include transform(translateY(0));
    @include transition(opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0.3s 0s, transform 0.3s 0s);
}
```

and it compiles to this:

```
.cd-dropdown.dropdown-is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity, visibility, -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition: opacity, visibility, -moz-transform;
    transition: opacity, visibility, transform; }
}
```

As you can see its not adding the seconds to the transitions....Any ideas anyone? If I change it to all, or just have a single property it will compile correctly, but if I try to chain it together - it breaks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're duplicating transition time in the function call:

```
@include transition(opacity 0.3s 0s, ...)
```

You have `0s` and `0.3s`. Maybe that's why it doesn't work. I checked the [transition doc](http://bourbon.io/docs/#transitions) and it seems like you have to put also transition type:

```
@include transition(opacity 0.3s ease-in 0s, ...)
```